# Regarding Global Discovery Server in OPC UA

Tags: opc-ua, opc

I am trying to make sense of the Global discovery mechanism observed in OPC UA.

1)Now, specification says, it is useful to find servers in an administrative domain. Just to clarify, here administrative domain means the top level of the automation pyramid? At the office level? Or does it mean that it can be used to find Servers across different networks?

2)I understand, GDS provides facilities for certificate management. Just ignoring the certificate manegement benefits of GDS for now, I would like to know how different of a discovery from multicast subnet discovery would it be?
because, according to[GDS Overview](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/v104/GDS/docs/6.1/), all of it is happening inside a single LAN.

3. In the same link, does it mean like there are 3 hosts existing? Where Host A has the LDS ME and the server which registers to its local LDS ME. Another host, Host B, has only a LDS ME running on it. So now Host A and Host B communicate via mDNS and each others cache is updated with records. Now GDS which is on Host C, is also on the same LAN. The LDS ME of host B registers to GDS. GDS, then calls for findServersOnNetwork with the LDSME, thus enabling to find details of all the servers.
4. How will an external client be able to see the records of the GDS?  I understand specification says use of a service("Query Servers").
   How will it be different from the LDS ME?

We get the same result from multicast subnet discovery as well.

Please let me know. Looking forward for any guidance.

Regards,
Rakshan

Comment: Ad 2. No, the GDS clients do not have to be on the same LAN.

Comment: @ZbynekZ thank you so much.. could you please tell me if my understanding on the other aspects of GDS is correct in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad 1. The administrative domain can be just about anything. It can be all the things you mentioned, or something else. It depends on the requirements there are for the system.

Ad 2. No, the GDS clients do not have to be on the same LAN.

Ad 3. In most general case, the picture you are referring to has 4 hosts (the 3 you have listed, plus the 4th one for the Client). Your description is otherwise correct except for this part: "Now GDS which is on Host C, is also on the same LAN." The GDS can be on a different LAN. There will be multiple "Host B"-s, one for each LAN that is "served" by the GDS.

Ad 4. An external client connects to a public endpoint of the GDS using normal OPC UA, and calls GDS and CM-related UA methods (not services) described in Part 12 of the UA specification, such as, yes, QueryServers, and more. The main difference from the LDS is that the client can get information about all servers in the administrative domain, not just those that are on its own LAN (or on the LAN it specifically connects to).

Comment: First of all, thank you for the detailed answer.. In( 3) I believe mDNS packets do not travel through the router, If the hosts are not on the same LAN, how would the GDS be aware of the servers on that network? It is little unclear to me.. (4) When you say CM related methods, you mean the findapplciations, register appliactions etc right? I have my servers running on LINUX environment, and the dotNet GDS is for the windows. I do not seem to understand how to go ahead...

Comment: You are right that mDNS packets do not travel through the router (in your example, between hosts B and C). There is no mDNS between them. The GDS needs to be configured explicitly to know about the LDS-ME installation, and it then uses normal OPC UA client-server communication to talk to the LDS. The descriptions below Figure 7 tell that clearly. "CM" is "certificate management", see https://reference.opcfoundation.org/v104/GDS/docs/7.1/ .The whole concept is platform independent. The concrete products, however (.NET GDS) can be platform limited. Pls mark the answer as accepted if you like it.

Comment: Hi @ZbynekZ, is there any way that I can access or extract the information model of the .NET GDS and use it in my C application? I mean with a different namespace? The reason i ask this, is because, currently for my work, security and certificate managing is out of scope. So if I am able toextract the GDS information model for discovery alone, i could experiment a bit. Please let me know

Comment: The information models are provided in form of "nodesets", https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Nodeset . The files are divided by spec part (Discovery is Part 12), but are not really meant to be used separately, and extracting just discovery but not CM is probably doable but not easy and you would be on your own doing that.

Comment: Hi @Zbynekz, sorry one more question.. If all of the devices ( 4 hosts mentioned above) are on the same host, would GDS make anything significantly different without CM facilties encorporated? Also in your prev answer --".The GDS needs to be configured explicitly to know about the LDS-ME installation, and it then uses normal OPC UA client-server communication to talk to the LDS."   Sorry, but when you say configured explicitly, what does it mean? Knowing the hostname and port of the GDS and register the LDS ME to GDS?

Comment: The CM part is not strictly necessary, the global registration/discovery can work without it. "Configured explicitly": That works in the opposite way. You need to tell the GDS where the LDS-ME-s are, and it can the get the info from them. In the article you have provided link to, it clearly says that: "2 The administrator registers LDS-ME installations with the GDS. 3 The GDS calls FindServersOnNetwork on the LDS-ME to find all applications on the same MulticastSubnet."